# Unable to connect to server: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "xxxx" FATAL: password authentication failed for user "xxxx"

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, pgadmin

I'm building a Django app and I'm trying to create a connection from AWS. The password is right and the hostname/address but after connecting it, it says

"Unable to connect to server:  FATAL: password authentication failed for user 'xxxx'"

Here's a screenshot of the error: https://prnt.sc/sqziuq

Other screenshots for another details of the connection:

https://prnt.sc/sqzm9z

https://prnt.sc/sqzlx7

Comment: Hi, are you using any funny characters in your password? I have encountered password issues with escape characters before for example. If so try with just letters and numbers to see if that works

Comment: Hello! My password has alphanumeric characters only and doesn't have special characters.

Comment: Hi, Any chance you can reset any credentials just to validate?

Comment: Will try it now. I'll let you know whether it works or not. Thanks!

Comment: I still encountered the same error after changing my password.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I specified was to reset the password.

This was confirmed to work.

Answer (score 3):

I just tried resetting my credentials in AWS and waited the status of my database to be available after modifying it.